# How do I read an Australian case citation and find the text of the judgement?

Tags: australia, case-law, legal-research

I want to know more about a particular case. I've seen it referred to a couple of different ways:

- *Tame v New South Wales* [2002] HCA 35
- *Tame v New South Wales* (2002) 211 CLR 317

How can I access information about these cases?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The quickest way to get the text of Australian judgements is through [AustLII](http://www.austlii.edu.au/).

#### Reading the citation

Parties:

> *Tame v New South Wales*

In this case, the parties are (Clare Janet) *Tame* and (the State of) *New South Wales*.

Year:

> [2002]

or

> (2002)

There is a subtle distinction between the above years: in brackets `[]` is *generally* (but not always) the year that the judgement was *made*, which may or may not be the year that the case was *reported*, which appears in parentheses `()`.

This case was both decided in, and reported in this law report, in 2002.

#### Court

> HCA

Where the citation includes brackets - `[]` - the abbreviation that follows is the *unique court identifier* of the court where the judgement occurred. This case was decided in the High Court of Australia. For a list of courts and abbreviations, see [AustLII's table of Australian case law](http://www2.austlii.edu.au/~davidv/alr/secure/tables/caselaw_table.html). **This is called a *medium-neutral* citation**.

Some reports are organised by year - unfortunately, there is no pattern to this - and they will have the year in brackets also. If more than one volume of a report of this kind is produced in this year, the volume number will appear between the year and the abbreviation as below.

#### Report number and series

> 211 CLR

Where the year appears in parentheses - `()` - and a number, then an abbreviation follows, these are the volume and abbreviation of the law report. In this case, it is the 221<sup>st</sup> volume of the Commonwealth Law Reports.

#### Pinpoint reference

> - *Tame v New South Wales* [2002] HCA **35**
> - *Tame v New South Wales* (2002) 211 CLR **317**

The final number is the *pinpoint reference*. In a medium-neutral citation, this is the judgement number - the *n*th judgement that year.

In all other cases, it is the page on which the judgement commences in the law report.

Authorised and authoritative law reports

All law reports are *authoritative* and can be employed in court, however the *authorised* law reports of a court are the *official* law reports - there is only one for each court. Judgements that highlight a novelty or a particular point of law are generally reported in the authorised law report.

### How to use a citation

The practical upshot of this is that AustLII provides [LawCite](http://www.austlii.edu.au/lawcite/), which is a free case citator - you can search for cases.

All you need is either:

- The year, court abbreviation, and judgement number, or
- The volume, report abbreviation, and page number

In the above examples, these would be

> - 2002 HCA 35, and
> - 211 CLR 317

... respectively. This is referred to in the citator as the citation (which is confusing because the entire thing is a citation).

LawCite provides, for your convenience, a table of:

- Cases that cite the case your case,
- Law reform reports referring to your case,
- Law journals referring to your case
- Legislation cited in the case your case, and
- Cases and articles cited in your case.

These are extremely useful in finding related cases during your research.